# SQL Update not working in a stored procedure unless run manually

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is a snipit of a stored procedure (a.k.a. sp) I have set up running on MSSQL(a.k.a. db). The sp is used to take data from a db view and export the results into a CSV file via BCP. This works with no issues. The last step is to update a db table, from which the db view is grabbing data, with a current time stamp. Now, here is my issue. When I manually run the stored procedure via MS SQL Server Management Studio, all works as planned. When the same sp is executed externally via software, the BCP export works yet the update table does not work, i.e. no current time stamp entry in the table. Declarations, variable sets, SET ANSI_NULLS ON and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON are all in place prior to this snipit.

Suggestions?

Curt

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DTicket WHERE FormID = @FormID)

BEGIN

   SELECT @csvdata = 'SELECT * FROM DTicket WHERE FormID = '''+@FormID+''''

   SELECT @bcpsql ='bcp "'+ @csvdata + '" queryout "'+ @filepath + @filename + '" -c -t"|" -U '+@user+' -P '+@pw+' -S '+ @server +' -d MainDB'

   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpsql

   UPDATE "udTicket" SET ExportDate = GetDate() WHERE  FormID = @FormID AND ExportDate IS NULL

END
```

Comment: do you start transaction as you execute your sp "externally"?

Comment: It may be that the app code isn't retrieving all the result sets so the proc doesn't actually finish executing. Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of the proc and specifying the no_output parameter: `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpsql, no_output;`.

Comment: Dan, Thank you!!! The no_output; was the trick!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql
Seem your update is happening before the bcp is done.
Capture the return value from xp_cmdshell like the example below

```
declare @rtn int

exec @rtn =EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpsql
if @rtn = 0
begin
UPDATE "udTicket" SET ExportDate = GetDate() WHERE  FormID = @FormID AND ExportDate IS NULL

end
 else .....
```